# Battery icon jump to front my overlay when battery loading or low

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, ios7

The battery icon jump to front my overlay when battery loading(icon change to green color) or low (icon change to red color). This occurs in iPhone and iPad.

Look snapshots:
[image]

[image]

Anyone been through this?

---

[Closed]
This is a default behavior on iOS. There isn't way to prevent it.

Comment: It's not jumping to the front, it is already there but them in black and not so visible. When the color comes in, either red or green, it is just more noticeable.

Comment: @rckoenes do you think so? It really looks like the green is way brighter than it should be. Salmo, how would the battery icon behave if you change the overlay to a opaque color?

Comment: Well the status bar is above your `UIWindow`, so I would guess that this is the reason.

Comment: I tested, it is same in front!